# Looking for a generic method to initialize misc View objects

Tags: android, object, initialization

I have a tab setup as an Activity extension using API8 max.
In this tab, I'm initializing some `TextView`, `EditText` and `SeekBar` objects like below.

I'm looking for a more universal method to be able to use a single method to initialize various object types (i.e. `TextView`, `EditText`, `SeekBar` and so on), passing the `View` type and `id` as argument, instead of using one method per `View` type.

In short, how to replace the 2 methods setTextViewObjects and setSeekbarObjects by a single generic method ?

```
private void initView(){
    mUnits = setTextViewObjects(R.id.textView16);
    mSeekBar = setSeekBarObjects(R.id.seek);
}

/**
 * Set TextView objects
 */
private TextView setTextViewObjects(int id){
    return (TextView) findViewById(id );
}

/**
 * Set Seekbar objects
 */
private SeekBar setSeekBarObjects(int id){
    return (SeekBar) findViewById(id );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <V extends View> V findView(int id) {
    return (V) findViewById(id);
}
```

Comment: usage for noobs like me :mUnits = ((TextView) setViewObject(R.id.textView16));